# Flex/PHP/XML data issue

Tags: xml, apache-flex

I've created a simple Flex application to fetch an XML file. I need a Flex variable "id" to grab the "letters" value from the  tag in the XML code, then show the id in an Alert window. When I run this code now (with the full code), the Alert box is blank.

When I run the application in Flex Debug mode, this is what Flex sees: http://static.readescdn.com/misc/flex.gif

Below is the Flex and XML code (edited to only show what's not working):

```
// Flex
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication ...
    creationComplete="windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            // Send the HTTP request
            protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                xmlService.send();
            }

            // Receive the HTTP response
            protected function xmlService_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                // Grab the id
                var id:String = xmlService.lastResult.data.id;

                // Show an alert with the id
                Alert.show(id);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:HTTPService id="xmlService"
                       url="http://localhost/file.xml"
                       method="GET"
                       useProxy="false"
                       resultFormat="e4x"
                       result="xmlService_resultHandler(event)"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:WindowedApplication>

// XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <id>letters</id>
  <letter label="Letter A">a</letter>
  <letter label="Letter B">b</letter>
  <letter label="Letter C">c</letter>
</data>
```

Comment: You need to narrow down your code and show us the problem area in question - paste a little code into your question, you can not expect people to go through all your code. In your question, you say that you can see the XML data being sent by the PHP to the flex client and then go on to say "however nothing is being received by Flex" - maybe you are not referencing what is being sent back by PHP correctly?

Comment: Sorry about that. Is that any better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorted...

```
var data:XML   =  event.result as XML;
var id:String  =  data.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "@id" instead of "id".

Comment: That resulted in an error in Flash Builder:

"1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before atsign"

Line: "var @id:String = xmlService.lastResult.data.id;"

Any ideas?